# Save Modern Site Page as Template

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, site-template, 2019, modern-pages

Slight dilemma.  I created a modern Site Page and want to save it as a template.  I tried many steps as you can see below.  Are there other ways to saving as a template?

1. Save as a Template not listed as an option under Save as a draft. (Why?)
2. Clicking promote on the menu bar does not give Save as a template as an option. (Why?)

Can this be done in SharePoint Designer for a modern (sharepoint 2019) site?

Answer (score 3):

The "Save as template" option only appears to be available in SharePoint Online:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/page-templates-in-sharepoint-faa92408-0c84-4e3d-8460-3c28065e7873